# Spring OAuth 2 and OpenAM integration, ClientContext per Session

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul

at the moment I am trying to integrate Spring-Security-Oauth2, Zuul, OpenAM as OAuth2 authorization Server and a WCF REST API as resource Server. The final Setup should look something like the following:

[image: Security]

I read the tutorial, which explains how to setup a SSO Environment with spring and AngularJS ([sso with spring and angularJS](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_sso_with_oauth2_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_v)), however in my case I would like to use OpenAM and password grant flow to authenticate useres.
So in the Spring Boot application my current config Looks as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class ApolloUIProxyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApolloUIProxyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.logout().and().antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/", "/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                    .addFilterAfter(authenticationProcessingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public ZuulFilter tokenRelayFilter(){
            JwtTokenRelayFilter filter = new JwtTokenRelayFilter();
            filter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate());
            return new JwtTokenRelayFilter();
        }

        @Bean
        public ZuulFilter customTokenFilter(){
            return new CustomZuulFilter();
        }

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter(){
            return new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        }

        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                            .getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null
                                && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }


        private OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter authenticationProcessingFilter(){
            OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter processingFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login");
            processingFilter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate());
            processingFilter.setTokenServices(resourceServerTokenServices());
            return processingFilter;
        }

        @Bean
        public ResourceServerTokenServices resourceServerTokenServices(){
            OpenAMRemoteTokenService remoteTokenServices = new OpenAMRemoteTokenService();
            remoteTokenServices.setRestTemplate(restTemplate());
            remoteTokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
            remoteTokenServices.setClientId("...");
            remoteTokenServices.setClientSecret("...");
            remoteTokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://...");
            return remoteTokenServices;
        }

        @Bean
        public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(){
            OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails(), clientContext());
            return template;
        }

        @Bean
        public AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider(){
            ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider provider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
            return provider;
        }

        @Bean
        public OAuth2ClientContext clientContext(){
            return new OpenAMClientContext();
        }

        @Bean
        public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails(){
            ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails details = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
            details.setGrantType("password");
            details.setAccessTokenUri("http://...");
            details.setScope(Arrays.asList("openid");
            details.setClientId("...");
            details.setClientSecret("...");
            return details;
        }

        @Bean
        public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter(){
            DefaultAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
            tokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(userAuthenticationConverter());
            return tokenConverter;
        }

        @Bean
        public UserAuthenticationConverter userAuthenticationConverter(){
            return new OpenAMUserAuthenticationConverter();
        }

    }
}
```

I wrote a custom RemoteTokenService, because otherwise Spring could not access the tokeninfo endpoint of OpenAM, which requires a GET-request and not a Post. This Connection works fine now, so that i get a valid access-token from OpenAM and can also query the tokeninfo.endpoint for token/user-Infos. The Authentication object gets created and is stored in the security-context of Spring. I can also access the Authentication Object in the ZuulFilter.

My Problem now is, that i had to tweek the "OAuth2ClientContext" to grab the users credentials from the servletRequest and put it on the "AccessTokenRequest". Otherwise I would have to hard-code them in the ResourceDetails, which is not appropriate in my case.

The result is, that the ClientContext (and also AccessTokenRequest I guess) is shared between all users of the System. What i want is a session scoped Client Context, so that I can have multiple useres logged in and can access the right SecurityContext for each user on every request.

So my question are,

1) how can I make the ClientContext and AccessTokenRequest session scoped?

2) Do I need to use Spring Session module?

3) Do I need to set the sessionStrategy

Thank you!

Comment: @scope( value="session", proxymode=scopedproxymode.TARGET_CLASS) on the OAuth2ClientContext helped, but I dont know if my solution is good in general